# How to view this .fits image without resizing and without modifying colors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, fits, aplpy

I am trying to open a full-color image from a `'.fits'` file. But, when comparing it to the corresponding `'.gif'` image, there appears to be an error regarding its color and size.

**How can I view the real-color image in its proper dimensions?**

As an example, one can select the `'.fits'` file and corresponding `'.gif'` file [located at the top of this webpage](http://soi.stanford.edu/cgi-bin/mdi/magday4.pl?mag=Mag&cr=2104). My example code, which uses the [APLPY](https://aplpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module, is below.

```
def from_fits_to_image(color_scheme, rloc, rname='synop_Ml_0.2104', rext='.fits', cmap=None):
    """ 
    color_scheme : 'rgb', 'grayscale', or 'false color'; color scheme of image to be shown
    rloc         : type <str>; location of file to be read
    rname        : type <str>; name of file to be read
    rext         : type <str>; extension of file to be read
    cmap         : None or type <str>; colormap
    """
    rpath = rloc + rname + rext
    if color_scheme == 'rgb':
        pic = aplpy.FITSFigure(rpath)
        # pic.show_rgb(alt_filename) # what filename is supposed to go here?
    else:
        pic = aplpy.FITSFigure(rpath)
        if color_scheme == 'grayscale':
            pic.show_grayscale()
        elif color_scheme == 'false color':
            if cmap is None:
                pic.show_colorscale()
            else:
                pic.show_colorscale(cmap=cmap)
    # plt.savefig(...)
    plt.show()
```

So long as one provides the proper `rloc` (the location of the downloaded `'.fits'` file) and `color_scheme`, the above code will run.

Calling the function below will show an empty plot of the proper dimensions. To make it non-empty, I must supply another existing filename, though I am unclear on what exactly that should be.

```
from_fits_to_image(color_scheme='rgb', rloc=rloc)
```

[image]

Each of the function calls below reveal a plot that has been resized to small. While `color_scheme='grayscale'` seems to colorize the plot properly, the other methods do not properly colorize the image.

```
from_fits_to_image('grayscale', rloc=rloc)
```

[image]

```
from_fits_to_image('false color', rloc=rloc)
```

[image]

```
from_fits_to_image('false color', rloc=rloc, cmap='plasma')
```

[image]

For comparison, the `'.gif'` image is below. Ideally, the output will look exactly like the image below.

**EDIT:**

I have tried using `astropy`, `PIL`, and `pyfits` unsuccessfully. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

Below is the result using `fits` from `astropy.io`.

```
from astropy.io import fits

def reada(rloc, rname='synop_Ml_0.1998', rext='.fits'):
    """ """
    rpath = rloc + rname + rext
    # hdu_list = fits.open(rpath)
    # hdu_list.info()
    pic = fits.getdata(rpath)
    plt.imshow(pic)
    plt.show()

reada(rloc=rloc)
```

I've played with the `vmin` and `vmax` kwargs, but to no success. Also, using `pyfits` to open the file results in the following error, even when using `pyfits.open(rpath, uint=True, do_not_scale_image_data=True)`:

```
TypeError: Image data can not convert to float
```

[image]

Comment: How is the gif image produced? Are you sure it's not a false color image? For true color rgb image you typically need to combine three images taken through red/green/blue filters, but the fits file you provide only has one image in it.

Comment: I am not sure how the images are produced, though the gif images at first glance appear correct because the image depicts the Sun’s surface over the course of one solar rotation. I will read the website for more information on this. As for combining three image filters, PIL and APLPY have methods to extract RGB- filtered data. Am I wrong to assume that the 3 RGB- filtered data arrays cannot be produced by sampling a picture three times (or once efficiently)? If not, is it possible to recreate the gif images from the fits images?

Comment: I am not sure if the 3 rgb images can be produced from a single array. Perhaps in solar astrophysics there are some tricks to do this, but the whole idea behind making an rgb image is to use three images, each one carrying independent information in it, so I doubt it.

Comment: Now that I look at it, I think your gif image is indeed a false color one. Hang on, I'll draft an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the gif, it seems that the image is a false-color one, and it's a matter of choosing a right color map. I can't say if there's an equivalent color map in python to the one you've linked to, but we can find something that is pretty close, recreating all the features in the image:

```
fig = aplpy.FITSFigure('synop_Ml_0.2104.fits')
fig.show_colorscale(vmin=-60, vmax=60, cmap='hot')
```

which shows the following (note that `aplpy` does not understand this coordinate system so it plots the figure in pixel coordinates):
[image]

The second part of the question is more tricky, and I can't fully answer it. Firstly, you need to convert the Carrington time into longitude, and sine latitude into degrees, and then plot the new values for the axis labels either instead of the old ones or as a parasite axes alongside the old ones (you can refer to an parasite axes example [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_parasite_axes2.html)).

Now it looks like the Carrington time is just degrees rotated since November 9, 1853, and the x-axis spans exactly 360, so I assume the conversion is simply an offset by 757079.95, the the x-axis value at the left edge. We can double-check it on the world coordinates, by looking at how the pixel span of the map corresponds to the coordinate span:

```
In [88]: fig._wcs.wcs_pix2world(fig._ax1.get_xlim(), fig._ax1.get_ylim(), origin=1)
Out[88]: [array([757439.95, 757079.95]), array([-1.,  1.])]
```

and the difference in values for the xaxis edges, 757079.95 and 757439.95, is exactly 360 degrees.

So then we can use some `matplotlib` tricks to manually offset the coordinate values to force them to go from zero to 360 and get the xaxis to match your gif image:

```
# using hidden attributes is non-pythonic but aplpy does not leave us other options
ax = fig._ax1
x_range = ax.get_xlim()
new_ticklabels = np.arange(60, 361, 60)
new_tick_positions = new_ticklabels / 360. * x_range[1] + x_range[0]
ax.set_xticks(new_tick_positions)
ax.set_xticklabels(new_ticklabels)
fig.axis_labels.set_xtext('Carrington Longitude')
```

[image]

Keep in mind that `aplpy` is a library designed for plotting celestial, not solar, coordinates, so getting the axes transform to work properly could be a rather painful process. An alternative way, and perhaps a better one, would be to plot the fits file with `sunpy`, a python [library](http://docs.sunpy.org/en/stable/guide/plotting.html) for solar physics. However, I have never used it, and it seems to throw an error for this particular fits file. Looks like you need to modify the header of the fits file to get the coordinates properly read. Perhaps you can get in touch with `sunpy` community if you want to use the library?

Comment: Wow, thank you for the thorough answer. I looked at the [SunPy documentation](http://docs.sunpy.org/en/stable/_modules/sunpy/io/fits.html) and it looks as though their method of reading fits files is a wrapper around astropy.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you choose values of vmin and vmax from the x-axis range divided by the number of xticks, was it arbitrarily chosen, or did you use a different method to select those values?

Comment: I plotted a histogram of the values and saw it was mostly peaked around +-50, so I plotted it in this rather arbitrary way.